# Pycharm remote interpreter deleted all files

Tags: pycharm

I tried using a remote interpreter in pycharm to connect using SFTP to another computer that is on the same network as the computer I'm working on.
I mapped my directory to the same directory on the other computer (the files are supposed to be shared on the network) however this ended up somehow clearing all the data in my folder. Thousands of files were changed. It seems that in my local history I can only restore .py files that were part of the project but is there anything else that can be done?
I think it is called synch and auto upload